# Libgdx. Screen organization

Tags: android, libgdx

Good day.

How can I organize screen like this?
[image]

I mean, that screen splitted on 2 parts: game scene and panel.
I'm using TiledMap for rendering game space.
My code:

```
map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/first.tmx");
mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1f / 32f);

cam = new OrthographicCamera(MyWorld.CAMERA_WIDTH, MyWorld.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
mapRenderer.setView(cam);
```

In that case game space fills whole screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two cameras and overlay them, one renders the game scene and the other the panel. Or if you use the libgdx `Stage` you can use two stages and draw the panel stage after the game scene stage.